# input accessible from image overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `input` field [using JSColor, color picker](http://jscolor.com/).
The color area on the left (the `input` text field) gets populated from the library which acts as the button.
[image]

**question:** Is it possible to have the image area on the right (`.arrowDiv`) so that i can click on the `input` text field underneath it? Underneath meaning `z-index`

The reasoning is because I can't seem to alter the library to detect clicks from anything other than the `input` text field

I couldn't make a fiddle because of url issues

css:

```
.input-container {
    position:relative; border:#999 1px solid; 
    height: 38px; width: 80px;
}
.arrowDiv{ 
    position:absolute; right:0; width:38px; height:38px; display:block; z-index:2;
    background: url("arrow.png") no-repeat scroll -335px 0 #F2F2F2;
}

.input-container input{
    float:left; margin:0; padding:0;
    width:75px; height:38px; 
    border:none;  background:transparent;   cursor:pointer;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="input-container">
    <input class="color">
    <div class="arrowDiv"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want to `display: none` the arrow drop down instead if it's to have no functionality?

Comment: @Dracorat but then i would not be able to see the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to click an element behind another element but I attached a small script to the div that will fire the open close events explained on the [demo page](http://jscolor.com/try.php). It's disappointing the library didn't have a `isOpen()` method so I had to store my own variable. I think I got what you were going for in this toy script. You'll want to tweak the code some though because the div hides values of the input element.

http://jsfiddle.net/jv6b7/

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to have the image area on the right (.arrowDiv) so that
>   i can click on the input text field underneath it?

Sure definitely.

Try setting the **top** property and the `left` property instead of `right`

```
.arrowDiv{ 
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:39px;
    width:80px;
    height:38px;
    display:block;
     z-index:2;
    background: url("arrow.png") no-repeat scroll -335px 0 #F2F2F2;
}
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/yGFmp/1/)**

**CSS** Setting the div size to that of the icon

```
.input-container {
    position:relative;
    border:#999 1px solid; 
    height: 38px;
    width: 80px;
}
.arrowDiv{ 
    position:absolute;
    left:60px;
    top:10px;
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
    display:block;
    z-index:2;
    background: url(http://i577.photobucket.com/albums/ss218/charles2690/11.png) no-repeat scroll;
}

.input-container input{
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:75px;
    height:38px; 
    border:none;
    background:transparent;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.arrowDiv').click(function() {
       // code to open the color picker
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/yGFmp/3/)**

Comment: Right click on the div and click on inspect element in chrome. Check if the image is present in the first place

Comment: also,  your fiddle pushes `arrowDiv` below the input. my question is about having those 2 elements side by side and being able to click through the image so that i am actually clicking the `input` element

Comment: I thought you wanted the div with arrow beneath the input

Comment: I would like to access the `input`, which is underneath the arrowDiv in terms of `z-index`

Comment: If you set the `z-index` of the input to greater than that of `arrowdiv` , then your div will be overlapped with your input. Then you won't see the image again.. One thing you can do is to handle the click event of the div and programmaticlly open it using javascript

Comment: yes, but then then the input's color will cover up the arrowDiv

Comment: You can set the size of the div to size of the icon. It will look like http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/yGFmp/2/